# Extract PDF bookmarks and compare them with parameters C#

Tags: c#, pdf

I have a question regarding bookmarks in PDF. 
I'm importing list of parameters from file and want to compare them with extracted bookmarks. I'm having troubles looping through list of imported parameters and my extracted bookmarks.
Can someone take a look at this piece of code and help me out a bit?
Thanks!

```
 public static void CompareBookmarks(string MyPDf, List<string> MyTitles)
        {

          PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(MyPdf);
          IList<Dictionary<string, object>> bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(reader);

          foreach (Dictionary<string, object> itemBookmark in bookmarks)

           {

             foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in itemBookmark)
             {
               foreach (var title in MyTitles)
               {

                     if (item.Value == str.ToString())
                     {
                        Console.WriteLine("Found");
                     }


                     else
                     {
                         Console.WriteLine("Not found");
                     }
                 }
             }

         }
```

Problem is, as I can see now, that each item in bookmark have 3 key/pair values(title, page number.). So the issue is- how can I compare only first value- Title with my string?

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason to enumerate all items in the bookmark since you are only interested in the title. So without testing, I would expect something like this:

```
foreach (Dictionary<string, object> bookmark in bookmarks)
{
  foreach (var title in MyTitles)
  {
    if (bookmark["Title"].ToString() == title)
    {
      // found
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void CompareBookmarks(string MyPDf, List<string> MyTitles)
    {

      PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(MyPdf);
      IList<Dictionary<string, object>> bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(reader);

      foreach (Dictionary<string, object> itemBookmark in bookmarks)

       {

        KeyValuePair<string, object> firstPairOfDictionary = item.FirstOrDefault();
               foreach (var title in myTitles)
               {

                  if (firstPairOfDictionary.Value != title.ToString())
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine("Did not found");
                       continue;
                   }

                   break;
               }

     }
```

The solution was to get first object in KeyValuePair.
I made a mistake and iterate through all objects in each bookmark.